# security scan for web application using ZAP, Chimera, or Burp

Tags: security-review, chimera-security-scanner

In my org am using the **Twilio** web application and cleared the security review using checkmark and when submitted I received an email to verify the **Twilio** using either **chimera or zap**.

**If your app integrates with the https://api.twilio.com endpoint, please confirm and provide Web Application scan results (from either ZAP, Chimera, or Burp), along with API documentation (e.g. sample HTTP request and response (for all header values).**

> Before starting a scan, you must configure your site to prove that you
>   are the owner. Chimera can only be used to scan web applications that
>   you own or develop. To do this, click on "Download Token" to download
>   your abuse prevention token. Follow the directions on that page to
>   upload the token to your domain. If you are absolutely unable to
>   upload the token to your server, please contact us using the address
>   on the download token page. We will grant exceptions in very rare
>   circumstances.

Am scanning web application (Twilio) how am I supposed to add token.

> This is the chimera scan required credentials. Is that correct what I
>   have entered

[image]

What is the step by step process to test the web-application detailed information will be helpful.

Comment: I'd also try and contact SF via a case to ask if you need to scan Twilio, since I think it is used internally by SF. But as an FYI, if you download ZAP, it doesn't need you to prove ownership - you can run it against any endpoint with the the caveat raised by dev-v1 re Twilio having an issue with you doing it...

Comment: @BritishBoyinDC thanks, man :) that's what Am doing downloaded the ZAP.  If you are familiar with ZAP then I have couple of questions- should I  run the site in browser so that ZAP scans or directly should I enter the URL in ZAP to attack ??

Comment: I entered the URL in ZAP to attack but it's taking more than a day to scan

Comment: I've always used the 'URL to Attack' feature, but it's on fairly small site I have permission to run it against, and it runs immediately and doesn't take very long. Sounds like Twilio might be blocking your attempts?

Comment: @BritishBoyinDC yeah I guess so it took more than 12 hrs and counting and number of URL's it's going on in lakhs- actually am using http://api.twilio.com as my endPoint,  I should scan only the endpoint which am using right ??  No point in scanning the https://twilio.com its the website  I will be scanning , when I scanned the https://api.twilio.com got the result pretty soon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would try and speak to SalesForce support about this, and possibly contact Twilio before doing any type of scanning. Most APIs will have a AUP or TOS that discourages users from using any type of vulnerability or code scanning against them.

> Attempting to bypass or break any security mechanism on any of the
>   Services or using the Services in any other manner that poses a
>   security or service risk to Twilio or any of its users.
>   https://www.twilio.com/legal/aup

Twilio's AUP is vague, so I would double check with them before running any automated tools against their site or API endpoint. In most cases, if you speak to the API provider, they can provide security and code details on request, that you can then in turn provide to SalesForce.